# How to read raster as array?

Tags: python

```
  from pyrsgis import raster
  from pyrsgis.convert import changeDimension

  # Assign file names

  greenareaband1='Sentinel-2  (2)dense.tiff'
  greenareaband2='Sentinel-2 L1C  (3)dense.tiff'
  greenareaband3='Sentinel-2 L1C  (4)dense.tiff'


  # Read the rasters as array
  df,myimage=raster.read(greenareaband1,bands='all')


  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ReadAsArray'
```

I keep getting this error but i'm sure that i have uploaded these images using
from google.colab import files
files.upload()

Comment: Please separate the error message from your code. Also try to include a minimal reproducible example if possible.

Comment: Please post the complete error traceback

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I discovered that I made a mistake on assigning the file name. Maybe there is a mistake there and thus, it is not recognized as a tif, and thence be able to ReadAsArray(). Hope that is the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issue here. Having two spaces and parentheses in your file name is the last thing you want to do in Python. Make sure that you have changed the working directory to where your file is or provide relative path and add 'r' in the beginning. For example:

```
input_file = r'E:/path_to_your_file/raster_file.tif'
ds, data_arr = raster.read(input_file)
```

About working with Colab. I think the best option would be upload you files on your Google drive and then authenticate your Colab script to mount drive. Then you just need to change the working directory like this:

```
# authenticate google drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# change working directory
os.chdir(r'/content/drive/My Drive/path_to_your_file')
```

Or, after mounting the drive simply do this:

```
input_file = r'/content/drive/My Drive/path_to_your_file/raster_file.tif'
ds, data_arr = raster.read(input_file)
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with non-trailing spaces, or parentheses,  in a Windows filename, in Python or any other language.

Comment: Python is sensitive to paranthesis at times so it is safer to avoid those. For instance, take a Pandas dataframe and try to search for '(' in a string type column, it wont happen unless you use '\('. About spaces, if you are using something that runs a sophisticated package like GDAL that runs some background processes in command, you may want to be a bit careful with spaces too.